# Why Get-PrinterProperty returns nothing but Get-Printer son0011 works?

Tags: windows, printer

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>  Get-Printer son0011

Name                           ComputerName    Type         DriverName                PortName        Shared   Published  De
                                                                                                                          vi
                                                                                                                          ce
                                                                                                                          Ty
                                                                                                                          pe
----                           ------------    ----         ----------                --------        ------   ---------  --
son0011                                        Local        HP LaserJet M605 PCL 6    son0011.ldl.... True     True       Pr
```

but

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PrinterProperty -PrinterName son0011

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

I can see the printer is present in devices and printers in windows server 2016?

NOTE : This is only happening for some of the printers and not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it on my laptop with my parent's printer, and it doesn't work either. According to a post by jrv (close to the end) in the thread below, if the printer doesn't have any configurable properties set, none will be returned when you run that command.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64787652-ad78-4570-bfeb-bee14c4dd1de/powershell-getprinterproperty-returns-empty-result?forum=winserverpowershell

I tried the command with some default Windows 10 printers (such as Fax, OneNote, etc.) and it works, but they only have 1 or 2 properties. So that's probably it.

On a side note, if you hadn't tried already, that command needs to be run with Admin Rights.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/get-printerproperty?view=win10-ps

```
You need administrator credentials to run Get-PrinterProperty.
```